# MSMQ - Message with Html

Tags: html, xml-serialization, msmq

I'm working on project using MSMQ, messages are both sent and received.

However, when trying to access the message body I get an error noting "Root element is missing"

I can't see the problem, but wondered whether the Html in the message body could be causing it.

Can MSMQ deal with Html? What about Xml Serialisation with HTML in the body elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using a BinaryMessageFormatter like this (and similarly on the receiving end):

```
using (MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\msmq1"))
        {
            queue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

            using (Message message = new Message())
            {
                message.Body = "<html><body>my html here</body></html>;
                message.Recoverable = true;

                message.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
                message.TimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                queue.Send(message);
            }
        }
```

Or create a MsmqTransportObject with an Html String property and transfer that instead.

The XmlMessageFormatter makes no sense if both the send and receive ends are using .NET (in which case you can safely use BinaryMessageFormatter)